# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in console if script tag is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this simple code not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.grid-lg').insertBefore('#menu-item-21');
});
</script>
```

I' read in console this error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)
```

When I remove the script tag everything works!

When I add the beggining and ending script tag I got that error and I'm confused about why and how I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: "if script tag is present" — present where? You've provided no context.

Comment: Have you added script tags within a JS file? In which case, it won't work...

Comment: I mean the end and closing of the scrip tag (scrript type="text/javascript") if I added my code to the console with that if doesn't work but when I remove the script tag it works

Comment: @JoJo why do you paste/put script tag in the console, that is not needed to run js.

Comment: I'm adding this code to my wordpress theme admin panel where It provides a field I can put my code to be in the header

Comment: "wordpress theme admin panel where It provides a field I can put my code to be in the header" — That doesn't tell us much. Look at the source code of the HTML document you then generate from WordPress. What does it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "this simple code" is in a JavaScript file (not an HTML file), you don't want the `script` tags. Those are HTML. "Everything works" when you remove them because they don't belong there.

This HTML:

```
<script src="somefile.js"></script>
```

loads the script. `somefile.js` wouldn't have the tags in it, because the tags are HTML, not JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.grid-lg').insertBefore('#menu-item-21');
});
```

---

> ...if I added my code to the console with that...

If you mean you're pasting it into the web console, again, that's a JavaScript environment, not HTML. You don't want HTML tags there, either.